# iterating through class members in groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a class named Vowels which contains 5 variables representing each vowel. User inputs a sentence, some voodoo magic happens and a method counts the vowels a prints them:

`[a = 9, e = 5, i = 7, o = 5, u = 6]`

After that the user is requested to input a random integer and another method does all 4 basic math operations as below:

```
input
3

output
a --> 9 * 3 = 27
a --> 9 / 3 = 3
a --> 9 + 3 = 12
a --> 9 - 3 = 6
```

So far I have managed to make this happen with 20 printlns (1 for each operation for each vowel), but could this be somehow optimized with a loop?
I found some info about reflection, but I don't really understand it.

Comment: It would help to share your code.  There will be a variety of solutions but most likely will depend on what you currently have

Comment: I don't see a great reason to have individual variables for the vowels; looks more like a simple map from string (letter) => int (count), which makes this trivial, and not require reflection at all. What's the justification for not doing the simplest thing?

Comment: I didn't think of that approach honestly, and I thought that making a class was the way to go. I'm not really an experienced programmer so every criticism is very welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The members of your object are available by calling `getProperties`.  Every object has a property named class, which you can ignore, and the order is not defined, so 'e' might appear in the properties before 'a'. Example:

```
class Vowels {
    int a, e, i, o, u
}

def v = new Vowels(a: 9, e: 5, i: 7, o: 5, u: 6)
v.properties.each { name, value ->
    if (name != 'class') {
        println "$name --> $value * 3 == ${value * 3}"
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ordering can be solved easily. `v.properties.sort { it.key }.each { name, value -> ... }` :)